# jQuery - access all elements from a each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a jquery function that gets hooked on all input elements like:

`$("input").blah();`

How can I access all elements of this type from within this function? not just the one that is currently processed by jQuery.

The function looks like:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.blah = function(){

     this.each(function(){

       // how can I access all elements of type "this" here?

       return this;
     });

 };

})(jQuery);
```

I want to read some attributes from all these elements, and then do some stuff to the current element that's being processed, based on those attributes

Comment: How do you define "this type"? Do you mean literally by the `type` attribute on the input?

Comment: The solution depends on what you're ultimately doing, but it sounds like you should filter them into groups if you need to act on them as a group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're hoping to filter the inputs based on the `type` attribute.

I don't know what you ultimately want to accomplish, but I'd say you probably don't want to do it in the `.each()` loop.

I'd filter the different types first, then do your loops.

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.blah = function(){

     var text = this.filter('[type=text]');
     var radio = this.filter('[type=radio]');
     var checkbox = this.filter('[type=checkbox]');

     text.each(function(){

       // do something with all "text" inputs

       return this;
     });

 };

})(jQuery);
```

An alternative would be to have just one loop, but perform a different action based on the value of `type`. This will only work if you don't need the collection as a whole.

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.blah = function(){

     this.each(function(){

        if( this.type === "text" ) {
            // do something with text inputs
        } else if( this.type === "checkbox" ) {
            // do something with checkboxes
        }
        // and so on

     });

 };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: +1 this is probably what she wanted. I think she wants to iterate over for example `text` then iterate over `this` with results of text.

Answer (score 6):

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.blah = function(){

     var that = this;
     this.each(function(index, element){

       // this here means the element in that[i]
       // that here means the original jQuery object.

       return this;
     });

 };

})(jQuery);
```

You can save `this` in a variable and then access in the `.each` callback.

Comment: can I use $(that).each(function) .. inside the first `each` ?

Comment: @Alexandra yes you can but it feels bad to do so. I recommend you do multiple `this.each` blocks rather then then nested blocks.

Answer (score 1):

`$('input').bind( "whatever", function() {
 $('input [type="' + $(this).attr( 'type' ) + '"] ).each( function () {
  //...whatever code here
  });
});`